# How to remove HTML attribute `pattern` in Prestashop 1.7, *classes/form/CustomerLoginFormatter.php*

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, formatter

My customer connexion form has a password field which contains `pattern=".{5,}"`. Since it's not a registration form, I would want to remove this HTML attribute.

Thus, I opened *classes/form/CustomerLoginForm.php* and I saw a `FormFormatterInterface` was used here: *classes/form/CustomerLoginFormatter.php*.

The latter contains:

```
public function getFormat()
{
    return [
        [...],
        'password' => (new FormField)
            ->setName('password')
            ->setType('password')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->setLabel($this->translator->trans(
                'Password', [], 'Shop.Forms.Labels'
            ))
            ->addConstraint('isPasswd'),
    ];
}
```

No line specify this HTML `pattern` attribute.

Where could I remove it? Should I write some setter or add some constraint in the above code? (in an override of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove that pattern from the file: `/themes/classic/templates/_partials/form-fields.tpl`

Search for this line and remove or change as your needs: `pattern=".{literal}{{/literal}5,{literal}}{/literal}"`

Comment: Will it remove this pattern only for this precise connexion form's field?

Comment: Nope. As I expected, all passwords fields of the site are affected by this modification :-). + You should explain why, when, and by what file is this TPL used, how it works. Your answer is quite helpful and I thank you, but it would be greatly better (and more Stackoverflow-compliant) if you gave more explanations about the whole process.

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler I don't understand you, you need an explanation why you need do the change in that file?, its because you can’t do the change in other file to remove that regex pattern.

Comment: Are you saying that it's impossible to remove this pattern attribute just for the connexion form password field :-)?